# How great a wizard is Cornelius Fudge?

Tags: harry-potter

I am currently reading the fourth chapter of Book 3 (The Prisoner of Azkaban).

I have seen that people respect Fudge in the magical world (for example: Tom, the owner of Leaky Cauldron, the bus driver of the Knight Bus, etc).

However, as far as I seen he isn't depicted as being as great as Dumbledore (in fact, not even close), and he tries to substitute activity for progress (where he arrests Hagrid just for the world to imply that *some activity* is happening).

So, is there any mention of how great a wizard he is? He is a Minister of Magic, which means that he must be very competent?

---

**Edited for clarification for the comments below:**

I understand that you don't need to be the best for becoming a Minister. But, atleast one needs to be competent enough to become one!

So, I'm asking about how competent was Cornelius Fudge.

Comment: This one is answered near the end of *Goblet of Fire*, where Dumbledore again maintains that it's people's decisions that matter. I should find the quote later and post an answer if nobody does by that time.

Comment: Remember that Fudge wasn't the first choice for Minister; Dumbledore was everybody's favourite. And he leant heavily on Dumbledore for advice for years. He was appointed sometime after Voldemort's first downfall, which means a lot of the most talented and capable candidates were dead. Basically, Fudge as Minister =/=> outstanding competency.

Comment: Just because you are a good wizard you are not automatically a good political leader and vice versa.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs Yeah, I understand that. But, for becoming a _Minister of Magic_, you must be atleast competent enough!  So, I'm asking about how competent is Fudge?  :)

Comment: **Warning - asking questions on a series that you haven't finished is very likely going to result in spoilers, intentional or not.** I'd recommend you store your questions for the end of the series, or if you must answer, specify no spoilers.

Comment: @DavidS Yeah, you are right.  Maybe I'll jot 'em down and ask after I complete the whole series :)

Comment: Even in the Muggle world, it's not the one who can shoot the best with a gun (and is the best in teaching others how to do it) is the one who is elected president.

Comment: @vsz Edited my question for clarification :)

Comment: @vsz But he would probably be, if the gun he head would form people isntead of killing them. You can't reduce magic to the functionallity of weapons. And you can't deny that if this magic would exist for sure people would be ruling who are the best of winning favors with their magic.

Comment: I'd argue that "for becoming a Minister of Magic, you must be atleast competent enough" ... in the political and sociological aspects of using, coordinating and regulating magic, and understanding of the wizarding community and it's inner politics and relations. It is an administrative (though influential) job that doesn't involve actually using any magic in it besides it's ordinary applications in communication and transportation. There's IMHO no good reason why a squib couldn't be an excellent minister of magic.

Comment: @Peteris Makes sense, a really nice point there :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're asking about his wizarding capabilities, I'd say he is not considered an exceptional wizard by any standards. Here is an example where Dumbledore easily beats Fudge, two wizards and one witch (all from the Ministry of Magic) in an attempt to arrest him(Dumbledore):

Order of the Phoenix (5<sup>th</sup> Harry Potter book), Chapter 27: The Centaur and the Sneak

> “So,” sneered Fudge, recovering himself, “you intend to take on Dawlish, Shacklebolt, Dolores, and myself single-handed, do you, Dumbledore?”
> “Merlin’s beard, no,” said Dumbledore, smiling. “Not unless you are foolish enough to force me to.”
> “Enough of this rubbish!” said Fudge, pulling out his own wand. “Dawlish! Shacklebolt! Take him!”
> A streak of silver light flashed around the room. There was a bang like a gunshot, and the floor trembled. A hand grabbed the scruff of Harry’s neck and forced him down on the floor as a second silver flash went off—several of the portraits yelled, Fawkes screeched, and a cloud of dust filled the air...
> Panting slightly, Harry saw a very tall figure moving toward them. “Are you all right?” said Dumbledore.
> “Yes!” said Professor McGonagall, getting up and dragging Harry and Marietta with her.
> The dust was clearing. The wreckage of the office loomed into view: Dumbledore’s desk had been overturned, all of the spindly tables had been knocked to the floor, their silver instruments in pieces. Fudge, Umbridge, Kingsley, and Dawlish lay motionless on the floor.

If he had any sort of superior magical ability, he would not be beaten so easily, even though Dumbledore is considered the best wizard of the generation.

If you're asking how he became Minister for Magic, Sirius Black explains to Harry, Ron and Hermione (Crouch was a very famous Ministry official and warrior against the Dark forces during Voldemort's first reign, but Crouch's son became a Death Eater, and was caught, tried and sent to Azkaban)

Goblet of Fire (4<sup>th</sup> Harry Potter book), Chapter 27: Padfoot Returns

> "So old Crouch lost it all, just when he thought he had it made,” he continued, wiping his mouth with the back of his hand. “One moment, a hero, poised to become Minister of Magic...next, his son dead, his wife dead, the family name dishonored, and, so I’ve heard since I escaped, a big drop in popularity. Once the boy had died, people started feeling a bit more sympathetic toward the son and started asking how a nice young lad from a good family had gone so badly astray. The conclusion was that his father never cared much for him.
> "So Cornelius Fudge got the top job, and Crouch was shunted sideways into the Department of International Magical Cooperation.”

As to whether he is a respected member of the magical society, well he was for a while. But in Order of the Phoenix we see Harry and Arthur Weasley speculating about him taking bribes from Malfoy. There is also the business of Fudge refusing to believe that Voldemort had returned at the end of the fourth book, and his harassment of Harry, Dumbledore and known Dumbledore supporters for the majority of the 5<sup>th</sup> book.

Comment: A **duel** has a very specific meaning in the HP universe, of which a 4-on-1 arrest probably doesn't qualify. Also, Shacklebolt was a member of the Order, meaning it was, at best, 3-on-1, and they were facing the most talented wizard in the world *on his home turf*. Fudge may be incompetent, but this isn't a good example of why; virtually anyone who isn't Voldemort would have had similar results.

Comment: +1 for quoting the best scene in the entire series, IMO.

Comment: It should be pointed out that they were in Dumbledore's sanctum, so they were already at a disadvantage, not counting the fact that he was the superior wizard.

Comment: Shacklebolt also assisted Dumbledore, so really it was 3-on-2, but Shacklebolt was a sleeper, so he and Dumbledore had the element of surprise. Against a sleeper Shacklebolt (one of the most skilled aurors in the Ministry) and Dumbledore himself (who had previously defeated the dark wizard Grindelwald in a duel), 3 middling wizards and witches don't stand a chance!

Comment: Why is each paragraph in its own spoiler?

Comment: @Salmononius2 And also a favourite scene in the movies: "_You may not like it Minister, but you can't deny... [Dumbledore's got style.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7iiMMq67_Q)_"

Comment: @WannabeCoder I know about the duel meaning, but couldn't find a better term for it. What would you suggest? 'Magic battle' or something to that effect?

Comment: @TylerH Well Shacklebolt assisted Dumbledore and Harry by Obliviating Marietta without being detected, but could not be seen not fighting Dumbledore. Hence he had to be hexed as well by Dumbledore. So while Shacklebolt might have tried not to hit Dumbledore with a spell(fire a spell but make sure it misses Dumbledore or something like that), he was definitely not fighting on Dumbledore's side.

Comment: @red_devil226 I seem to recall specifically from the book that Kingsley hexed Dawlish from behind. Not sure when it is mentioned though; later on, I think.

Comment: Now that you mention it I think I can remember that as well. But there is another scene later where Dumbledore talks about his displeasure at having to hex Dawlish 'once again', when Dawlish was set by the Ministry to tail Dumbledore. I'm assuming this scene would be the first time.

Comment: @red_devil226 I would call it exactly what it was - an (attempted) arrest. Dumbledore was the only one to fire a spell, and that was the start and end of the "battle." Not to mention if we're qualifying anyone who Dumbledore defeated in this scenario as "not an exceptional wizard" - then I suppose Shacklebolt and Dawlish are incompetent as well - and that's just silly.

Comment: Let's also not forget that there's more to being a wizard than fighting ability. For all we know, Fudge is exceptional at Charms or Runes. That's like judging the Prime Minister on his ability to box.

Comment: ...it seems weird to me to summarise the events of a paragraph, then spoiler tag the actual paragraph. The spoiler damage has already been done by that point. Why not say "Here's an example that shows Dumbledore is a better wizard - spoilers for book 5"

Comment: @WannabeCoder Duly noted and edited. As to the point on judging Fudge's magical strength, I was trying to relate it to when Voldemort was fighting McGonagall, Slughorn and Shacklebolt together at the end of the seventh book. We know that all three of them have decent magical ability and hence they were able to hold Voldemort off for a while at least. Voldemort's ability is almost equal to that of Dumbledore. If Fudge had even barely comparable abilty, he would have been able to put up a fight. Especially since Dumbledore had given him prior warning on his decision not to "go quietly".

Answer (score 18):

### Not very.

From [this Pottermore article by JK Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/order-of-merlin) (emphasis mine):

> As often happens with such highly coveted awards, Ministry of Magic favourites seem to receive the Order of Merlin, especially the higher classes, more often than one might expect. While nobody argued when Albus Dumbledore received his O.M. (First Class) for defeating the Dark wizard Grindelwald, there was a good deal of muttering in the wizarding community when **Cornelius Fudge**, Minister for Magic, awarded himself an O.M. (First Class) for **a career that many considered less than distinguished**. Other less worthy recipients of the highest class of Order include Arcturus Black, Sirius Black’s grandfather, who was widely believed to have bought it by loaning the Ministry a large amount of gold.

For a Muggle comparison, see [Leonid Ilyich Brezhnev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonid_Brezhnev#Cult_of_personality) (thanks DVK!):

[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer could benefit from including a picture of Leonid Ilyitch Brezhnev :)

Comment: @DVK Sorry, you'll have to explain that one ...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonid_Brezhnev#Cult_of_personality and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awards_and_decorations_received_by_Leonid_Brezhnev

Comment: Basically, a Muggle Russian Fudge. In far more ways than one, self-given top honor medals included.

Comment: @DVK better now? :-)

Comment: http://www.chelnyltd.ru/images/article/3_14077_pic_10%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%94.jpg ?

Comment: http://www.belvpo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/5_1_brezhnev_paradny_700-300x251.jpg ?  (no, that's NOT a 4-chan fake. Official portrait)

Comment: @DVK only if there's a corresponding picture of a bemedalled Fudge...

Comment: @DVK If I could upvote this post again just for Brezhnev, I would.

Comment: @randal'thor -  you can post both Brezhnev pics, one yours one medalled. Your call, of course! :)

Comment: "Other less worthy recipients of the highest class of Order include Arcturus Black, Sirius Black’s grandfather, who was widely believed to have bought it by loaning the Ministry a large amount of gold." ... honestly :) Why would people (or JKR in that case) think that donating a big sum of money is a bad thing. Especially to a governmental institution that will most likely spend at least part of the money for the public.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other two answers:

Fudge is a disappointment, really.
IMO, he's no better than any other wizard and he's a typical politician.
If you're in the third book, you should already have read how he was in the Leaky Cauldron, and he's corrupt, bribing and getting bribed, even, from the right people.

Once you're near the end of the fourth book, Harry'll have a revelation of Fudge that I got to share with him, and I was not happy.

He could be an Auror(assuming you need to be that to be in a high-ranking Ministry position), but he never shows that kind of magical talent anytime in the series.